# Data Binding for images using sql ce for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have been using the sql ce to bring some data onto my application. Now I need to add some of the images to make it look pretty. What all I want to know is

1. There must be some image to byte conversion done,
2. Retrieve the image byte code and convert back into the image.

I've got stuck at the second part and how am I supposed to continue?

Any links or examples are needed for the reference.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some ideas I have used in the past.

The image column in the DB:

```
[Column]
public byte[] MyImage
{
  get { return _myImage; }
  set
  {
    if (_myImage != value)
    {
      _myImage = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanging("MyImage");
      NotifyPropertyChanged("MyImage");
    }
  }
}
```

Save image:

```
public void AddNewImage(Stream image, string url)
{
  byte[] byteArray = GetImageBytes(image);

  var item = new MyDatabaseItem { Count = 1, ItemImageUrl = url, MyImage = byteArray };
  MyDatabaseItemModel.Add(item);
  MyDatabaseDB.MyDatabaseItems.InsertOnSubmit(item);
  MyDatabaseDB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Get image:

```
private byte[] GetImageBytes(Stream stream)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    var writeableBitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(stream, 200, 200);
    writeableBitmap .SaveJpeg(ms, 200, 200, 0, 30);
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Using a value converter:

```
public class ImageConverter: IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is byte[])
    {
      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(value as byte[]);
      varwriteBitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memoryStream, 200, 200);
      return writeBitmap;
    }
    else
      return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally bind it in XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Comment: Oops I missed 
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Phone; these references. Sorry for that

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanging returns this error 'is a type but used as a variable'. Did I miss something here?

Comment: There was this resource could not be resolved.. is there anything else to add?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are having problems with. Have you looked at the basics of using SQL CE on Windows Phone? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Yes sir, im stuck at converting the byte array from db to image.

Comment: "doesn't work" "I'm stuck", "there was this... " sorry dude, but my psycic powers are failing me today. You really have to learn to report any error messages, compilation error or whatever. It's *impossible* to help you based on "I'm stuck"

Comment: Yeah the mistake was to create a stub value in the table.cs page. Now everything works exceptionally fine. :)